# Django admin using date_hierarchy with unix timestamp

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model like:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    source_time = TimestampField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

and I would like to enable in the admin page the date_hierachy like this:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('source_time', 'price', 'quantity')
    date_hierarchy = 'source_time'
```

but it requires a DateTime.
I tried to do a custom field derived from DateTime which will convert the BigIntegerField into a DateTimeField but I got this error:
"Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'long' object has no attribute 'year'"

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime, mktime
import time

class TimestampField(models.DateTimeField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    def __init__(self, null = False, **kwargs):
        super(TimestampField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'bigint'

    def to_python(self, value):
        super(TimestampField, self)
        try:
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(float(value)/1000000)
        except:
            return value
```

Shouldn't the new custom field behave exactly as a DateTimeField?
How could I make date_hierarchy work if I have a BigInteger field in the table?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your new `date_hierarchy` based on existing code. See file: `django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py`, line 235.

Comment: how would you override `def date_hierarchy(cl):` for a single ModelAdmin?